# Linux - Search text in a file and join in another file

Tags: linux, awk, sed

I have two text files:

`File-1`:

```
PRKCZ
TNFRSF14
PRDM16
MTHFR
```

`File-2`(contains two tab delimited columns):

```
atherosclerosis   GRAB1|PRKCZ|TTN
cardiomyopathy,hypercholesterolemia    PRKCZ|MTHFR
Pulmonary arterial hypertension,arrhythmia   PRDM16|APOE|GATA4
```

Now, for each name in `File-1`, print also the corresponding diseases names from `File-2` where it matches. So the output would be:

```
PRKCZ    atherosclerosis,cardiomyopathy,hypercholesterolemia
PRDM16    Pulmonary arterial hypertension,arrhythmia
MTHFR    cardiomyopathy,hypercholesterolemia
```

I have tried the code:

```
$ awk '{k=$1}
        NR==FNR{if(NR>1)a[k]=","b"="$1";else{a[k]="";b=$1}next}
        k in a{print $0a[k]}' File1 File2
```

but I obtained no desired output. Can anybody correct/help please.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this with the following awk script:

**script.awk**

```
BEGIN { FS="[\t]" }
NR==FNR { split($2, tmp, "|")
          for( ind in tmp ) {
            name = tmp[ ind ]
            if (name in disease) { disease[ name ] = disease[ name ] "," $1 }
            else { disease[ name ] = $1 }
          }
          next
        }

        { if( $1 in disease) print $1, disease[ $1 ] }
```

Use it like this `awk -f script.awk File-2 File-1` (note first `File-2`).

**Explanation:**

- the `BEGIN` block sets up tab as separator.
- the `NR == FNR` block is executed for the first argument (`File-2`): it reads the diseases with the names, splits the names and then appends the disease to a dictionary under each of the names
- the last block is executed only (due to the `next` in the previous block) for the second argument (`File-1`): it outputs the diseases that are stored under the name (taken from `$1`)